# Who delivered Amidala's body back to Naboo?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, padme

In *Revenge of the Sith*, after first being Force-choked by Anakin and then given births to Luke and Leia, Padme Amidala eventually lost her life on Polis Massa. We later, however, see her in the funeral procession on Naboo. The question is, how did she get there?

[image: Padme Amidala]

I mean, whoever delivered her there must have faced a lot of difficult questions, not just from her family but also from both the people and the authorities, since she was the former queen of the planet. Whoever it was, he could not have been just somebody, because it most certainly must not have been an easy task. It most likely was not any of the Jedi, since the world was probably half full of Palpatine's collaborators who would have immediately given them away.

So, who was it? And how was it carried out, in practice?

Comment: The Force delivered her.

Answer (score 11):

After her death, Bail Organa (in the [Sundered Heart](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sundered_Heart)) took the Jedi to their destinations on Tatooine and Dagobah. Presumably this included dropping Padmé's body off at Naboo en route.

> *“To Naboo, send her body …” Yoda stretched his head high, as though
>   tasting a current in the Force. “Pregnant, she must still appear.
>   Hidden, safe, the children must be kept. Foundation of the new Jedi
>   Order, they will be.”*
>
> ...
>
> *Obi-Wan and Yoda watched the funeral from Bail Organa’s starcruiser.
>   It was as close as they dared come. The Emperor’s attention would
>   surely be fixed on the funeral, and they would not take the risk of
>   being found.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Junior Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(junior_novelization))</sup></sub>

As far as the *circumstances* of her death were concerned, it was apparently [not Naboobian tradition to ask too many questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114875/did-padm%C3%A9-have-any-family). Her family were simply informed that the Jedi murdered her on Coruscant during their attempted coup.

[image]

---

Further down the canon, the EU novel [Dark Lord: The Rise of Darth Vader](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Lord:_The_Rise_of_Darth_Vader) contains the following info

> Holocams at the Temple or in the former Republic Plaza might easily
>   have captured his speeder, and those images could have found their way
>   to Palpatine or his security advisers. **Word might have leaked that
>   Bail was the person who had arranged for Padme to be delivered to
>   Naboo for the funeral.** If Palpatine had been apprised of that fact, he
>   might begin to wonder if Obi-Wan, having carried Padme from distant
>   Mustafar, had informed Bail about Palpatine’s secret identity, or
>   about the horrors committed on Coruscant by Anakin, renamed Darth
>   Vader by the Sith Lord, whom Obi-Wan had left for dead on the volcanic
>   world.
>
> And then Palpatine might begin to wonder if Padme’s child, or
>   children, had in fact died with her…

This seems to lend weight to the idea that Bail didn't visit her family *personally*, but perhaps waited in orbit while one of his men went down.

Comment: That's great research, however, it reveals us only that "Padme's parents were told she was killed by the Jedi". Told by who?

Comment: @Essen - Good question, dunno. It's not described in any canon reference I'm aware of. Probably Bail Organa since he's pretending to be super pro-Empire.

Comment: @Essen - Anakin/Vader knows that Padme left with Obi-Wan, Artoo and R2-D2 after the fight. If the Empire asked how her body got onto his ship, he could just lie and say that one of the droids contacted him on her orders before dying.

Comment: Boots contain cushioned inserts?

Comment: Ahh, found the full page.  I was thinking it was special funeral attire or something.  http://smg.photobucket.com/user/SnakePlisken/media/VD_31_Padm.jpg.html

Comment: @mskfisher - Well, pregnancy attire. To help her cope with not being stick-thin any more.

Comment: Is *Naboobian* the official word for, um, Nabooninites?

Comment: @ruakh - Sadly, no. The correct term is Naboo (as in "the Naboo did x") but *Naboobians* is far funnier.

Comment: The Legends book *Dark Lord* also [features](http://books.google.com/books?id=bIBC5lu-_K4C&lpg=PP1&pg=PT96) Bail Organa worrying about being targeted by the new Empire, and has the line "Word might have leaked that Bail was the person who had arranged for Padmé to be delivered to Naboo for the funeral." I guess "arranged for" suggests he didn't deliver the body personally though.

Comment: Just a note, you say *Dark Lord* is "further down the canon", but I believe the current Disney canon doesn't treat either pre-2014 novelizations or visual dictionaries as canonical, see [this tweet from Pablo Hidalgo responding to a question about the novels](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/712038897065304067).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - The novelisations are considered canonical where they [match what happened on screen](https://twitter.com/delreystarwars/status/461579307341840384) or, presumably, elaborate on something *described but not seen*. Where they're non-canonical is where they describe something that didn't happen on screen (such as altering dialogue) or conflict with an existing scene.

Comment: I would disagree with your "presumably"--Pablo Hidalgo's comment pretty clearly says the writers don't feel beholden to *anything* published before 2014, only to what was shown onscreen in the films and *The Clone Wars*. I think Hidalgo, who's in the LucasFilm Story Group, would be more trustworthy on this than Del Ray Books which was presumably getting their info secondhand, and which also showed some confusion given that their [earlier tweet](http://twitter.com/delreystarwars/status/461541040273764352) just said flat out the novels were canon, then they had to make that "clarification".

Comment: @Hypnosifl -  I don't think anyone is disagreeing with that. The point is that the novels are canon, but only to a point and that point is *where they agree with what happened in the films*. Where they disagree, they're Legends (with a capital L) and where they elaborate, they're a sort of wibbly-wobbly grey area that no-one wants to talk about because it might harm book sales.